# Blank lines or \par break xparse or ifthen macro

Tags: xparse, conditionals

Leaving blank line break simple macro but `%` terminating it fixes it. What's going on? I know one is supposed to use `%`, but I can't have any blank lines in the macro without it complaining. A blank line essentially terminates the macro and TeX complains about a mixing `}`. Using `etoolbox` also produces the same problem so it seems it is an issue with `xparse`.

Is there any way to fix `xparse` package so I don't have to litter my code with `%`s?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse, ifthen, etoolbox}


\NewDocumentCommand\iftb{m m G{\relax}}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{#2}{#3}}

%\NewDocumentCommand\iftb{m m G{\relax}}{\ifbool{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newboolean{A}\setboolean{A}{true}
\newboolean{B}\setboolean{B}{true}


\begin{document}

\iftb{A}{%
% <- remove all text on this line breaks macro (keep blank line)
    \iftb{B}{%
        asdffdsasdff
        % <- same here
        asdf
    }
}

End
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Macros defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` by default don't accept `\par` (or empty lines, which is the same) in their arguments.

You can overcome this behavior by adding `+` in front of an argument specifier that can possibly contain a `\par`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\iftb{m +m +G{\relax}}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{#2}{#3}}
```

or

```
\NewDocumentCommand\iftb{m +m +G{\relax}}{\ifbool{#1}{#2}{#3}}
```

The macros on which `\ifthenelse` and `\ifbool` are built already accept `\par`.

---

The question why `\par` is not accepted in macro arguments comes from the fact that this is the default behavior for macros, as Knuth imagined them.

A macro defined with

```
\def\macro#1{...}
```

doesn't accept `\par` in its argument. Knuth thought that this can catch the common error of forgetting the closing brace and wanted to avoid that such a mistake could lead to reading in all the current file looking for the closing brace.

However a macro definition can be prefixed by `\long`: so

```
\long\def\macro#1{...}
```

allows empty lines in the argument of `\macro`.

LaTeX's `\newcommand` is of course built on `\def` and by default prefixes it with `\long`; the *-form `\newcommand*` doesn't.

The function `\NewDocumentCommand` (also `\DeclareDocumentCommand`, but the `New` variety should be preferred, for it provides a check against redefinitions) take the `\newcommand*` approach, but in a slightly different way: each argument can be declared "long" or not (by default it isn't), while with `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*` all arguments are treated equal.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why, by default, \par and empty lines are not accepted?

Comment: @AbstractDissonance It is a feature built in to TeX at the most primitive level so that (in a latex context) a typo like `\documentclass{article` with no closing `}` stops at the first paragraph not the end of the document.

Comment: Awesome. We learn everyday.