# Blank lines in argument cause failure

Tags: tcolorbox, xparse

For some reasons, `\NewDocumentCommand` from `xparse` package other than `\newcommand` from Latex has to be used to construct my macro. 
Yet I find in some situations blank lines in arguments of my macro will lead to failure of compile.
The following link gives explanation：
[blank lines break xparse or ifthen macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64328/blank-lines-break-xparse-or-ifthen-macro)

However, my example code below still fail to compile. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

    \begin{document}

    \NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{+O{}m}{% notice "+O{}"
      \begin{tcbitemize}[#1]
        #2
      \end{tcbitemize}
    }
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \mycmd[
    colback=yellow,

    coltext=red
    ]
    {\tcbitem some text}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem hass nothing to do with `xparse`: you get the same problem if you have a blank line in the optional argument to `tcbitemize` because such optional arguments do not accept blank lines.

Comment: "Long" macros allow multiple paragraphs (blank lines), and are produced using `\newcommand` or `\long\def`.  "Normal" macros do NOT allow multiple paragraphs in their arguments, and are produced using `\newcommand*` or `\def`.

Comment: For my example, is there a solution?

Comment: @lyl Not using blank lines in key-value specifications is *the* solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem, as Andrew said in the comment, is not your `\mycmd`, but it's deeper down in PGF's key parser. The problem is reported in the `\pgfkeys@addpath` macro.

The first, and trivial alternative, is to remove the blank line. A paragraph break doesn't make much sense in that context. And if you want a visual separation between keys you can always comment the line end:

```
\mycmd[
colback=yellow,
% <- here
coltext=red
]
```

The second alternative *could* be to redefine `\pgfkeys@addpath` to make it long. Spoiler alert: another macro will probably complain shortly after because the `\par` token will be passed on through the key-value parser. But suppose you manage to make all (!) these macros `\long`. Then the parser would, eventually, see a key-value pair like this: `\par coltext=red`. The parser is coded such that it trims *spaces* around the keys, but `\par` is not a space, so at the very least you would have to rewrite some of the parser to make it remove `\par` tokens as well.

If we're removing `\par` tokens, then we can go straight to the third alternative, which is to remove them much earlier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \LylTmpaTl
\cs_new:Npn \StripPar #1 #2
  {
    \tl_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
    \tl_remove_all:Nn #1 { \par }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{+O{}m}{% notice "+O{}"
  \StripPar\LylTmpaTl{#1}% Removing ALL \par tokens
  % Trick to expand \LylTmpaTl once
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand
  \begin{tcbitemize}[\unexpanded\expandafter{\LylTmpaTl}]}\x
    #2
  \end{tcbitemize}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mycmd[
colback=yellow,

coltext=red
]
{\tcbitem some text}

\end{document}
```

This method will remove *all* par tokens from the option list. Even the ones you don't want to be removed, but it's the price you have to pay. If you happen to want a `\par` token somewhere in the value to a key you'd have to use `\endgraf` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The internal macros of Ti*k*Z/PGF that control key-value assignments don't allow for `\par` tokens and it's *a good thing*™ they don't.

Your input

```
colback=yellow,

coltext=red
```

is completely equivalent to

```
colback=yellow,\par coltext=red
```

and obviously there is no `\par coltext` key. In order to avoid the issue, the macros are explicitly defined as *not long*, so not allowing `\par` in their argument.

Recall that TeX automatically transforms a blank line into a `\par` token *at the time input is read in*.

The fact you marked the optional argument as long (with `+`) doesn't “remove” the wrong `\par` token, it just allows to accept it at argument absorbing time. But then the argument is passed to other macros that should be able to accept it: well, they *can't* accept it.